# PostgreSQL DROP VIEW IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view

In PostgreSQL when I run the command

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_name;
```

I get the response:

```
View IF dropped.
```

Can anyone explain what this means? why the word '**`IF`**' instead of a response like: **`View view_name dropped`** ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not what PostgreSQL does. Demo:

```
postgres=# create view view_name as select 1;
CREATE VIEW

postgres=# drop view if exists view_name;
DROP VIEW

postgres=# \echo :SERVER_VERSION_NUM
110002

postgres=# drop view if exists view_name;
NOTICE:  view "view_name" does not exist, skipping
DROP VIEW
```

Possibly you're not using PostgreSQL proper, but rather a fork that has a different syntax for this operation. Check out the result of `SELECT version();`.

Comment: Thank you @daniel-vérité -- It's a PostgreSQL running on a RDS instance in AWS. The SELECT version outcome is: "PostgreSQL 10.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit"

Comment: @russellelbert: if you run the commands under psql (with a remote connection to RDS), you should get the same results as in my answer above. I suspect that the `View IF dropped` message comes from a SQL client that tries to interpret the statement and doesn't do it well enough.

Comment: Gotchya, that makes total sense. Thanks again for your help!